# Why this recursive call works this way?

Tags: c++, recursion, g++4.8

I was implementing a segment tree for **RSQ**. I observed something that doesn't make sense. Here is a reproduced version of the original code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class ST {
    private:
    int siz, mid;
    void build(int n, int l, int r)
    {
        cout << n << " " << l << " " << r << endl;
        if(l == r){
            //some op
        } else {
            mid = (l+r)/2;
            build(2*n, l, mid);
            build(2*n+1, mid+1, r);
            //some op
        }
    }
    public:
    ST(vector<int> &x)
    {
        siz = x.size();
        build(1, 0, siz-1);
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> p;
    int t, z;

    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> z;
        p.push_back(z);
    }
    ST c(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Now if the vector p is of size 3, first time build called with (1, 0, 2) as expected. But it should be recursively get down to `build(2, 0, 1)` and `build(3, 2, 2)`. the first one works correctly where the second one called as `build(3, 1, 2)`. It seems that `mid+1` is producing `mid`. What did I miss?

`g++ -v` shows **gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)**

Comment: Why is `mid` an instance variable? It looks like all `build` calls in the call tree share the same `mid`.

Comment: @user2357112 That shouldn't be a problem as function parameters are guaranteed to be evaluated before function call. right? Well, I am new to the paradigm. so, I don't know what is the correct way to have a local variable.

Comment: you call build twice, for the second call mid will be already overwritten by the first call

Comment: lack of sleep effect maybe. thanks both of you. I must not again use instance variable in place of local variable. You may consider posting your comment as answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments - build is called twice in a row and for the second call mid instance variable is already overwritten by the first call.

I did not post this initially as an answer because even when I made mid a local variable I still could not get your expected numbers. But glad it helped :)